# Form validation Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I just have a confusion in UI Validation plugin using.

In our application, we are using **Spring MVC, Jquery & Bootstrap**. And we start up with UI construction and got a confusion to go with which Validation plugin.

Can someone advice me with your experience which validation framework is good for covering below scenario's?

**1) Large form

2) With lot of inner tab

3) Confirmation popup's

4) Form submission is through Ajax call(In our case, form saving and will stay in same form screen with all submitted value's)**

Today, i saw few

**1) Query Validation Plugin (jquery-validate-1.15.0)

2) Bootstrap Validation Plugin (bootstrap-validator-0.5.3)

3) Validator.js**

Sorry i may be wrong in understanding above plugin's, I am not full stack UI developer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First your project required server side validation or client side?

Comment: @ranjan - Client side validation. As all forms are going to be big, we don't want to go back and forth...

Comment: so better to go for Jquery validation plugin like https://codepen.io/jaycbrf/pen/iBszr

Comment: So you say's Bootstrap validation plugin? Can i go with latest version 0.5.3?

Comment: yes but current version is v3.3.7  http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: v3.3.7 is for core bootstrap framework js & css. Bootstrap validator is 0.5.3 is latest version i guess.  https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.bootstrapvalidator

Comment: Okay you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used and like the jQuery Validation plugin more than anyone below is a brief description of it from its [website](https://jqueryvalidation.org/):

> This jQuery plugin makes simple clientside form validation easy,
> whilst still offering plenty of customization options. It makes a good
> choice if you’re building something new from scratch, but also when
> you’re trying to integrate something into an existing application with
> lots of existing markup. The plugin comes bundled with a useful set of
> validation methods, including URL and email validation, while
> providing an API to write your own methods. All bundled methods come
> with default error messages in english and translations into 37 other
> languages.
>
> — [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

GitHub status of your candidate plugins as of `20 Aug 2016`:

**jquery-validation**: Issues: 74, Watches: 426, Stars: 6686, Forks: 2066
[image]

**bootstrap-validator**: Issues: 37, Watches: 76, Stars: 1335, Forks: 643
[image]

**validate.js**: Issues: 26, Watches: 16, Stars: 736, Forks: 85
[image]